# Hybris Cockpit - Populate a Drop-down list with model data items

Tags: zk, sap-commerce-cloud

How to populate a `Drop-Down` list created in a custom wizard in the `Hybris` cockpit with the model data `items`?

The wizard is designed with **ZK framework** components (in a **.zul** extension file).

Comment: Can you develop your question/requirement ?

Comment: Are you working in Hybris Backoffice ? Which Hybris Version ? Did you create a widget or separated custom wizard ?

Comment: @Ясир  I am using Hybris Version 5.7, with a custom cockpit. The data is fetched from mysql databse. There exist already different data models , and DAO interface and its implementation class to access the data through mysql queries. I have created a separated custom wizard, and I want to populate the drop-down list created in that wizard with one of the data models. The drop-down list is created as a combo-box from ZK framework.

Comment: @Nomade  I have also created a Wizard class and defined its bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `drop-down` list in Hybris Cockpit Wizards, you need to call the Hybris native editor bean named `shortListEditor` in the `MyItem` xml configuration file. To go more further in the solution you need to :

- Locat the wizard xml configuration file, often named  `wizardConfig_MyItem.xml`.
- Add attribute (the `myAttribute` should be a List or Enum) to `MyItem` structure.
- Add xml configuration for your attribute :

  - If `myAttribute` a `List` add : `<property qualifier='MyItem.myAttribute' editorCode='shortListEditor'>`
  - If `myAttribute` an `Enum` add : `<property qualifier='MyItem.myAttribute' editorCode='shortListEditor'>`

Comment: Are you pointing to Editor Area of cockpit? I forgot to mention that the wizard appears as a new pop-up window in cockpit, when I press the new custom button, which I have created. In that wizard I have a drop-down list.

Comment: In this case, I'am pointing to the Items Wizard popups. I will edit my answer to help you how you can achieve that.